# Value for "Global auto (prl)" to fill default_preferred_network on build.prop

Tags: sms, mobile-network

My Smartfren Andromax A with LineageOS 15.1 can't send & receive SMS unless I set my default preferred network to **global auto (prl)** and then perform a hot reboot.

I have an idea to edit my `build.prop` to make **global auto (prl)** as the default preferred network but I don't know what value I need to fill, not much luck when I check on `include/telephony/ril.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ro.telephony.default_network=10` on `build.prop`, it will make the device uses global auto (prl) as the default preferred network.